# How do I rotate a image 360 degree around is own axis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, rotation, axis

I have tried for two days now to find a way to rotate my image while i input a button. What i want help with is to help me get the code to rotate a image in Javascript called `images[0]` around its own axis. I know this may look hard but i have tried aswell and I really need help from professionals.

Comment: 360 degrees is back where it started, so you can do nothing. But what have you tried? Can you post your code and a link to your jsfidddle?

Comment: What i am more asking for is if their is any way to do 90 degree rotation while pressing a button, and the rotation 90 degree again while pressing another key ( I have fixed the part with input key thing)

Comment: At 90 degrees the image will be side on and not viewable, you also haven't stated around which access you are trying to rotate

Comment: I am just asking for help to rotate a image 90 degree like this:
U (rotate 90degree) c or something like this: < (rotate 90degree) ^
This is a simple illustration of what i want to happen to my image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

Based upon [Xotic750](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592253/xotic750)'s jsfiddle, [**here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcMkv/17/) using [*animation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation) and [*@keyframes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) (using *-webkit-* prefix, modify for other browsers).

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes r {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
#r:hover ~ img {
    -webkit-animation: r 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes y {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
#y:hover ~ img {
    -webkit-animation: y 2s infinite linear;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="r">R</button>
<button id="y">Y</button>
<br/> <br/>
<img src="http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/2656/impreza20061sh5.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Paul S has provided a much better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262172/592253).

Here is an example of rotating an image 90 degrees

CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#container:hover #card, #container.hover_effect #card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

HMTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="card">
        <img src="http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/2656/impreza20061sh5.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bcMkv/)